# Hibernate Search add only DocumentId from IndexedEmbedded class

Tags: hibernate-search

I've an Entity "Invoice" and this one has a many-to-one relationship to Customer-Entity. This Customer-Entity is also used from other Entities for Hibernate Search and so there are many Hibernate Search annotations. For Invoice HS-Index I just want to have the Customer.id in the Invoice index and no other property of Customer.
How is this possible, because in the documentation I've found nothing specific about it.

Comment: Which version of Hibernate Search are you using?

Comment: We are using version 3.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In recent versions of Hibernate Search, you would simply use `@IndexedEmbedded(includePaths = "id")`.

Hibernate Search 3.4 is very old, though (9 years old), and is missing many features. I'd recommend you upgrade since you're very likely to hit bugs that will never be solved in this version.

If you really have to stick with 3.4, I believe your only solution will be writing a custom bridge:

```java
public class CustomerIdBridge implements StringBridge {

    public String objectToString(Object object) {
        Customer customer = (Customer) object;
        if ( customer == null ) {
           return null;
        }
        Object id = customer.getId();
        return id == null ? null : id.toString();
    }
}
```

Then apply the bridge like this:

```java
@ManyToOne(...)
@Field(bridge = @FieldBridge(impl = CustomerIdBridge.class))
private Customer customer;
```

The resulting field will simply be named "customer" (same name as your property).

See [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/3.4/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e3582) for more information about bridges in Hibernate Search 3.4.2.

Comment: Thanks a lot yrodiere I'll try this.